WPF StaticResource Not Found in UserControl - Resource Defined in App.xaml
I'm working on a WPF project where I define a global style for a TextBlock in App.xaml, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to reference it in a UserControl. The application throws an error saying that the resource key cannot be found.
My App.xaml looks like this:
<Application x:Class="Reservoom.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="Header">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>


In my UserControl, I try to reference the Header style:
<UserControl x:Class="Reservoom.Views.ReservationListingView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="View Reservations" Style="{StaticResource Header}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>


When I run the application, I get the following error:
 System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message='Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '19' and line position '31'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at Reservoom.Views.ReservationListingView.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\farok\source\repos\Reservoom\Reservoom\Views\ReservationListingView.xaml:line 1

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Why is the StaticResource defined in App.xaml not accessible in my UserControl? What is the correct way to reference global resources in a WPF UserControl?

I verified that the App.xaml is loading properly and the Header style is defined.
I tried changing StaticResource to DynamicResource, which resolves the error but doesn't feel like the right solution in this case, since I expect the resource to be static and available throughout the app.
I also considered merging resource dictionaries explicitly in the UserControl, but I thought resources defined in App.xaml should be available globally.


This seems to work when I spun something up. Is the user control apart of the main project?

@Byrd Yes, the UserControl is part of the main project. It resides in the Views folder of the same project where the App.xaml is located. The style for TextBlock is defined in App.xaml, and I'm referencing it in the UserControl.
The app runs into the issue when I use {StaticResource Header} in the UserControl, but switching to {DynamicResource Header} works, although I'd prefer to understand why StaticResource isn't functioning as expected.
Could there be something specific about how WPF handles resources in UserControl versus Window?

There shouldn't be an issue with this specific case since it's not using any other resources for the header style. It's just changing the font. Both resources are created when the xaml is parsed. But static is loaded once and will ignore changes. Dynamic is a reference and you can actually change the style with some pre loaded event. I believe the only differences. Maybe this is a situation with the user control loading bad data when the static resource is parsed defined or assigned? It is saying index out of bounds. Which doesn't make much sense considering the style is such a simple change.
